# Are there other web alternatives of Google Reader?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-reader, rss

I assume probably most of you use Google Reader for following and reading RSS or Atom feeds. My question is are there any web alternatives that some of you have used and are happy with?

Comment: [New question since google reader decommission has been announced](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/alternatives-for-google-reader)

Comment: One of the questions should be closed as duplicate. Whoever has the rep, please vote.