# Are there any good web-based feed readers (besides Google Reader)?

Tags: rss, feeds, rss-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there other web alternatives of Google Reader?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/are-there-other-web-alternatives-of-google-reader)

Bloglines is closing down in a couple of weeks. I've been looking hard for a web-based feed reader that can handle around 400 feeds. I've visited too many links pointing to feed readers that have now discontinued their service. If I move my feeds to a new reader, I'd prefer that they stay alive for at least a few months.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with Google Reader?

Comment: Many things are wrong but mainly the fact that items older than a month are marked as read. There's also a limit of 10k most recent items that can be unread.

Comment: If you have _that_ many unread items, do you really think you'll get to them...? That sounds like a compounding problem. If you see articles you think you'll actually get to, you should Star them or tag them in Google Reader.

Comment: If you have a few high-volume feeds they will take up that 10k limit in less than a week. I won't read all the items in those feeds but they will drown out any feeds that I only read once a week or once a month.

Comment: One option is to use something like Yahoo Pipes to filter the high volume feed and subscribe to that feed instead.  Or evaluate the value you get from that feed and unsubscribe from it instead to focus on the feeds that you care about.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Firefox, I recommend feedly. It's not an alternative to Google Reader, but you can integrate your Google account with it.

Comment: Not exactly a web-based feed reader. Suffers from the same problems as Google Reader.

Answer (score 2):

[FastLadder](http://fastladder.com/help/) <strike>or [BlogLines](http://www.bloglines.com/) are</strike> is a possible web based option.

Comment: FastLadder can  handle 1000+ feeds.

Comment: Bloglines is shutting down, hence the reason for the question.

Comment: Bonus points for suggesting FastLadder, looks like it could be a decent choice for me. They also have an open source version that you can host yourself. Minus points for not reading the question, as the first four words are "Bloglines is closing down".

Comment: FastLadder was an excellent replacement for BlogLines, but FastLadder will now be shut down on May 31, 2012.

Answer (score 1):

> [Netvibes.](http://www.netvibes.com/en)
>
> It is a personalized start-page
>   (*highly recommend!*), and has RSS
>   modules that work well...worth a
>   look...

-

> [FeadBucket.](http://feedbucket.com/)  Looks interesting,
>   no personal experience...

-

> [Top 10 Web-based RSS readers - SpeckyBoy.com](http://speckyboy.com/2008/05/31/top-10-web-based-rss-readers/)

Comment: I don't like the dashboard-style interface of Netvibes at all. FeedBucket doesn't look very trustworthy and has very little information on the homepage. And that list is from 2008 and most services linked to have been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Unix-like server running Apache, PHP, and MySQL and are willing to host your own feed reader, you can try [Fever](http://feedafever.com/). I haven't tried it but I've heard very good things about it, and since it's hosted on your own server, whether or not it stays alive is entirely up to you.

Comment: I did in fact buy Fever last week, it doesn't look like it can handle my 400+ feeds very well. The interface makes a non-consistent use of AJAX, as well as incremental flushing of output from PHP. I don't think I like it overall, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Feedingo](http://feedingo.com/). It has been around for a little while, with the intent to be a better feed reader. I've used it a little bit, it's quite nice, though am undecided whether to switch from Reader.

Comment: I see they changed their pricing, now it's $10/month for only 100 feeds, used to be $10/month for up to 500 feeds (which would have worked for me). They also seem to be light on features beyond the very basic stuff.