# Free Google Reader alternative with mobile web version

Tags: google-reader, rss-reader

I mean something like that (http://www.google.com/reader/i):

[image]

What I've tried:

- Feedly - no mobile web version
- NewsBlur - paid for more than 12 feeds (I have more)
- Netvibes - mobile version not usable in Opera Mobile on Android (wap version isn't counted)
- Pulse - don't know even how to import rss from Google Reader there o_O Finally managed to import, but this doesn't look like to be a reader for something more serious than 9gag because of "tiles" view
- TinyRss - own hosting needed
- Fever - paid, own hosting needed (?)
- Bloglines = Netvies
- Feedshow - no mobile web version
- NewsAlloy - no ability to import feeds from Google Reader?
- Daily Rotation - something strange...
- My Yahoo - no import from Google Reader
- Bazqux - paid, no mobile web version
- Feederator - no import from Google Reader
- Goodnoows - no mobile web version
- PublicRSS - no mobile web version
- FeedBooster - not managed to login from mobile device o_O
- 1kpl.us - no mobile web version
- ContentGems - paid, no mobile web version
- Alesti - no mobile web version
- Kedoya - no mobile web version
- AOL Reader - mobile web version is not usable in Opera mobile for Android
- Digg Reader - no mobile web version

to be continued ...

Comment: Is there really nothing in [Alternatives for Google Reader (with Android synchronizing)](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/alternatives-for-google-reader-with-android-synchronizing/) that fits the bill?

Comment: @batpigandme I hope that somebody have already researched it. But it seems that I have to do it by myself, so I'll edit my question to tell what I've tried.

Comment: Always helpful to know what you've tried!

Comment: There is an Android app for Feedly. There's also FeedMe, which recently acquired Feedly integration.

Comment: @AlEverett I need mobile web version, not standalone app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedly started to work ok, finally

[image]

Comment: I get redirected to the "Get Feedly For Android" page at www.feedly.com.

Comment: @Yang set user-agent "Desktop" in settings

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered [Pulse](https://www.pulse.me/).

[image]

It's good looking and easy to use. Plus, if you sign up with your Google account, you get all your RSS feeds integrated automatically - just scroll down the page to where it says "Import Your Google Feeder Reads".

Comment: Tried it on PC - it seems that there is even no ability to import rss from Google Reader o_O (it suggested to sign up only with facebook or as new user)

Comment: If you scroll down the home page, the first item is "Import Your Google Reader Feeds". It's pretty straightforward from there.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson maybe integrate your comment into the answer for posterity?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson Ah, this option wasn't able for registered user >< Finally, I've imported feeds, but Pulse really looks like "9gag reader", I don't see a way to read my 40+ feeds structurized.

Comment: @janot Yeah, I haven't used it enough to help you organize your feeds, but a little googling will probably help you. Also, remember to select my answer if it solved your problem. It helps both our repuutations.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson I think it's not possible because of "tiles" view

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Feedly - no mobile version

However, Feedly has native Apps for iOS and Android.
Plus, you may configure the user interface to be very similar to the old Reader.

Comment: sorry, I meant "no mobile web version"

Answer (score 0):

Feedly is evolving a lot lately and now has a web version ([cloud.feedly.com](http://cloud.feedly.com)) and has an open API, which allows a lot of other apps to use Feedly as feeds provider.
On Android, I use [gReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.reader&hl=en) which is much better than the Feedly mobile app.

The only major drawback I find is the lack of an export feature but they said it will be added in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

[AOL Reader](http://reader.aol.com/) — in beta at the moment

And there will be [Digg Reader](http://digg.com/reader) as well.

Comment: AOL: "You're on the beta list.
We've reached full capacity. We will send you a link to verify you email to the address you provided us as soon as we can. Follow that link and we'll put you on the beta access list."

Comment: I've received link to verify - mobile web version is unusable

Comment: Try the [Digg Reader](http://digg.com/reader) then—it’s open for public now.

Comment: Already tried - no mobile web version

Answer (score 0):

Try:

http://www.protopage.com

http://protopage.com/mobile

Protopage was one of the first online feed readers, and obviously still continues to offer features none of the others do.

Comment: What features? An answer should not completely rely on an external link.

Comment: Oh right, I listed the site as an answer to the question, i.e., it is a news feeder with a mobile site as opposed to a mobile application.  To list all of the features on the mobile site would take some time; I don't think it has unread counts on the mobile view, but it does have very good facilities for structuring feeds.

Comment: Obviously I will have missed some features here; like I said, I was answering the title question.

Comment: Looks great, really. About unread counts - at least it shows what's unread and what's not. But I have problem with importing *.opml from feedly to protopage =/ Maybe you know, what's the problem? It tells, that I upload not valid *.opml file.

Comment: Just looks great, but in fact is impossible to use, when you have a lot of feeds (all of them will be displayed)

Answer (score -1):

Try [skimr](http://www.skimr.co), it has a very good mobile web interface (basically the same as the non-mobile web interface but scaled down). My only problem with it is that there are no unread item counters. Good for casual reading though.

Comment: yeah, looks rather good but no unread items counter =/