# Google Reader alternatives that also have iOS apps

Tags: rss, google-reader, rss-reader, ios

Like many others, I'm looking for a Google Reader alternative now that it is shutting down. However, I'm also looking for an alternative that has an iOS app that I can use. Currently, I use the Reeder app, which only supports Google Reader (shutting down), Readability (can only read articles that are saved to there), and Fever (needs my own server to host it).

So, anyone know a good feed reader that also has a nice iOS app? Of course, the app doesn't have to be developed by the feed reader creators. For instance, if the feed reader has a nice API, then someone else might have developed an app for it.

Comment: I think this question is a little close to the [other](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/alternatives-for-google-reader) [questions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/are-there-other-web-alternatives-of-google-reader) already on this topic. Most of the popular options have apps for iOS and Android, a new question for every device isn't helpful.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll keep track of those posts instead.

Comment: I did edit that question to include iOS apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular Google Reader alternative seems to be [Feedly](http://www.feedly.com/). It also has an iOS app.